# How to add UIView on UICollectionView and scroll with cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I need to add two overlays on the uicollectionview(the bottom one), and these overlays need to scroll with cell, please help

[image]

Comment: You can add scrollView to top and bottom and change the scrollView content offset based on the collectionView's scrollView content offset. Simple enough

Answer (score 2):

You should provide a more detailed description of your question.

If the overlay is scrolling *with* the cell, why not make it a subview *of* the cell and set `cell.clipsToBounds = NO;`?